# Closed form of series $\sum_{n=\frac {1}{2}}^{\infty}\Gamma (1-s,xn)e^{xn}n^{s-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, divergent-series, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

I'm trying to get some closed form solution of $\sum_{n=\frac {1}{2}}^{\infty}\Gamma (1-s,xn)e^{xn}n^{s-1}$. To be precise gotten closed form should be analytic continuation for any given $x$. There are no specified function of closed form. For example for $x=0$ it's just $\Gamma (1-s)\zeta (1-s,\frac {1}{2}) $ and this is absolutely satyfying result, because if given series is divergent I can just use analytic continuation of Hurwitz zeta function.

PS:What I mean by sum from  $n=\frac {1}{2} $ is for example anagously  $\sum_{n=0}^a n=\frac {a (a+1)}{2} $. So for $a=\frac {1}{2}$ we get $\frac {3}{8} $

Comment: What is the range of the summation index?

Comment: From $n=\frac {1}{2}$ to $\infty $. I mean it is posible to define it as that. But standard series from $n=1$ to $\infty $ will be good as well. Maybe just assume some more general solution from $n=a $ to $\infty $

Comment: What does $\sum_{n=a}^\infty$ mean when $a$ is not an integer?

Comment: Let's use some example $\sum_{n=0}^a n$ (I changed $a$ to upper boundry of summation but it's analogous). Closed form sollution of this series is equal to $\frac {a (a+1)}{2} $. Just put $a=\frac {1}{2} $ and it's done

Answer (score 2):

Here are some first thoughts.

We have that
$$\Gamma(1-s,xn) = \int_{xn}^\infty t^{-s} e^{-t}dt$$
It is much more convenient to turn this into
$$\Gamma(1-s,xn) = \int_{0}^\infty t^{-s} e^{-t}dt-\int_{0}^{xn} t^{-s} e^{-t}dt$$
Then we change variables so that we have for the first part
$$\int_{0}^{xn} t^{-s} e^{-t}dt = nx \int_0^1 (nxt)^{-s} e^{-nxt} dt$$
Now, to deal with the original series, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Gamma(1-s,xn) e^{xn} n^{s-1} = \int_0^\infty t^{-s} e^{-t} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{xn} n^{s-1} dt = \Gamma(1-s)Li_{-s+1}(e^x)$$

For the second piece
$$\int_0^1 (tx)^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} e^{-nxt}e^{xn} n^{s-1} dt = \int_0^1 (tx)^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (e^{x(1-t)})^n = x^{-s}\int_0^1 t^{-s} Li_1(e^{x(1-t)}) dt$$
So the final result is that the series equals
$$\Gamma(1-s)Li_{-s+1}(e^x)- x^{-s}\int_0^1 t^{-s} Li_1(e^{x(1-t)}) dt$$
Probably, there is extra analysis needed to understand exactly what the effect of replacing the divergent series in the inner summation with $Li$ does to the function. I suspect there is a branch cut somewhere, probably at negative values of $s$.

Is there a specific context you have in mind for working with this series? I could tailor my analysis a bit if you have something particular you're wanting to do this series.

Comment: Yes, there is reason to work on it. I was working on general functional-equation like representation of analytic continuation of Infinite series. The theorem I derived gives correct results on https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/19740cee6db60c818e9a23f29b7daf16940ff3ce but I wonder if that will work on https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e67043fb1f93df77872da29efd9a3843bdf22278  being valid for all $x $

Comment: Theorem looks like that. $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f (k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathscr {L}\{ f \} (2 \pi i n)$. But it has symbolic meaning. To get functional equation from equation you have to break summation from $-\infty $ to $\infty $ at some point $a $ and get analytic continuation of Laplace transform and series. Try it for yourselfe with $f (k)=z^k k^{-s}$ and $a =\frac {1}{2} $. You will actualy get equation from first link. So I wanted to find out if there exist equation from second link valid to all x